How to send messages using libp2p through a functions in Rust?
I'm working on a Rust project where I need to send and receive messages using libp2p.
I have set up a basic libp2p structure with gossipsub for message propagation and mdns for peer discovery.
I used the chat example from the libp2p GitHub repository here. In this example, stdin is used to input messages. However, I need to send gossip messages from a function outside of the loop with custom data.
My question is: How can I send a gossip message from a function outside of the process_messages loop?
I'm looking for a way to create a separate sender that can be called to send messages independently of the receiving loop.
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
Here's a simplified version of my current code setup:
use crate::node::blockchain::Blockchain;
use crate::node::transaction::Transaction;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use futures::FutureExt;
use libp2p::{
    gossipsub, gossipsub::Event as GossipsubEvent, gossipsub::IdentTopic, gossipsub::MessageId,
    mdns, mdns::Event as MdnsEvent, noise, swarm::NetworkBehaviour, swarm::Swarm,
    swarm::SwarmEvent, tcp, yamux, Multiaddr, PeerId,
};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::error::Error;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;
use tokio::{io, select, sync::Mutex};
use tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter;

#[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]
pub struct P2PBehaviour {
    pub gossipsub: gossipsub::Behaviour,
    pub mdns: mdns::tokio::Behaviour,
}

pub struct P2PServer {
    pub behaviour: Swarm<P2PBehaviour>,
    pub topic: IdentTopic,
}

impl P2PServer {
    pub fn new(topic_name: &str) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut swarm = Self::build_swarm()?;
        let topic = Self::setup_gossipsub_topic(&mut swarm, topic_name)?;

        Ok(Self {
            behaviour: swarm,
            topic,
        })
    }

    pub fn send_gossip_message(
        &mut self,
        message: &str,
    ) -> Result<MessageId, gossipsub::PublishError> {
        self.behaviour
            .behaviour_mut()
            .gossipsub
            .publish(self.topic.clone(), message.as_bytes())
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self, blockchain: Arc<Mutex<Blockchain>>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        Self::setup_tracing()?;
        Self::listen_for_connections(&mut self.behaviour)?;
        self.process_messages(blockchain).await
    }

    fn setup_tracing() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        tracing_subscriber::fmt()
            .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::from_default_env())
            .try_init()
            .expect("Failed to setup tracing");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn build_swarm() -> Result<Swarm<P2PBehaviour>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let swarm = libp2p::SwarmBuilder::with_new_identity()
            .with_tokio()
            .with_tcp(
                tcp::Config::default(),
                noise::Config::new,
                yamux::Config::default,
            )?
            .with_quic()
            .with_behaviour(|key| {
                let message_id_fn = |message: &gossipsub::Message| {
                    let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
                    message.data.hash(&mut s);
                    gossipsub::MessageId::from(s.finish().to_string())
                };

                let gossipsub_config = gossipsub::ConfigBuilder::default()
                    .heartbeat_interval(Duration::from_secs(10))
                    .validation_mode(gossipsub::ValidationMode::Strict)
                    .message_id_fn(message_id_fn)
                    .build()
                    .map_err(|msg| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, msg))?;

                let gossipsub = gossipsub::Behaviour::new(
                    gossipsub::MessageAuthenticity::Signed(key.clone()),
                    gossipsub_config,
                )?;

                let mdns = mdns::tokio::Behaviour::new(
                    mdns::Config::default(),
                    key.public().to_peer_id(),
                )?;
                Ok(P2PBehaviour { gossipsub, mdns })
            })?
            .with_swarm_config(|c| c.with_idle_connection_timeout(Duration::from_secs(60)))
            .build();
        Ok(swarm)
    }

    fn setup_gossipsub_topic(
        swarm: &mut Swarm<P2PBehaviour>,
        topic_name: &str,
    ) -> Result<IdentTopic, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let topic = IdentTopic::new(topic_name);
        swarm.behaviour_mut().gossipsub.subscribe(&topic)?;
        Ok(topic)
    }

    fn listen_for_connections(swarm: &mut Swarm<P2PBehaviour>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        swarm.listen_on("/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0".parse()?)?;
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn process_messages(
        &mut self,
        blockchain: Arc<Mutex<Blockchain>>,
    ) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_secs(5));
        loop {
            select! {
                event = self.behaviour.select_next_some().fuse() => {
                    Self::handle_swarm_event(event, &mut self.behaviour, &blockchain).await;
                },
                _ = interval.tick() => {
                    let message = format!("Periodic message at {:?}", std::time::SystemTime::now());
                    if let Err(e) = self.send_gossip_message(&message) {
                        println!("Publish error: {e:?}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async fn handle_swarm_event(
        event: SwarmEvent<P2PBehaviourEvent>,
        swarm: &mut Swarm<P2PBehaviour>,
        blockchain: &Arc<Mutex<Blockchain>>,
    ) {
        match event {
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(P2PBehaviourEvent::Mdns(MdnsEvent::Discovered(list))) => {
                Self::handle_mdns_discovered(swarm, list);
            }
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(P2PBehaviourEvent::Mdns(MdnsEvent::Expired(list))) => {
                Self::handle_mdns_expired(swarm, list);
            }
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(P2PBehaviourEvent::Gossipsub(GossipsubEvent::Message {
                propagation_source: peer_id,
                message_id: id,
                message,
            })) => {
                Self::handle_gossipsub_message(peer_id, id, message, blockchain).await;
            }
            SwarmEvent::NewListenAddr { address, .. } => {
                println!("Local node is listening on {address}");
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn handle_mdns_discovered(swarm: &mut Swarm<P2PBehaviour>, list: Vec<(PeerId, Multiaddr)>) {
        for (peer_id, _multiaddr) in list {
            println!("mDNS discovered a new peer: {peer_id}");
            swarm.behaviour_mut().gossipsub.add_explicit_peer(&peer_id);
        }
    }

    fn handle_mdns_expired(swarm: &mut Swarm<P2PBehaviour>, list: Vec<(PeerId, Multiaddr)>) {
        for (peer_id, _multiaddr) in list {
            println!("mDNS discover peer has expired: {peer_id}");
            swarm
                .behaviour_mut()
                .gossipsub
                .remove_explicit_peer(&peer_id);
        }
    }

    async fn handle_gossipsub_message(
        peer_id: PeerId,
        id: MessageId,
        message: gossipsub::Message,
        blockchain: &Arc<Mutex<Blockchain>>,
    ) {
        println!(
            "Got message: '{}' with id: {id} from peer: {peer_id}",
            String::from_utf8_lossy(&message.data),
        );

        // handle_received_transaction(message, blockchain).await;
    }
}

async fn handle_received_transaction(
    message: gossipsub::Message,
    blockchain: &Arc<Mutex<Blockchain>>,
) {
    let transaction_result: Result<Transaction, _> = serde_json::from_slice(&message.data);

    if let Ok(transaction) = transaction_result {
        println!("Transaction received");

        let transaction_added = {
            let blockchain = blockchain.lock().await;
            blockchain.add_transaction_to_pool(&transaction).is_ok()
        };

        if transaction_added {
            println!("Transaction added");
        } else {
            println!("Failed to add transaction to pool");
        }
    } else {
        println!("Failed to deserialize transaction");
    }
}


(rust-libp2p contributor here)
It's great that you try your hand at libp2p!
High level
What you typically want is to separate the libp2p functionality from the rest of your application. You then communicate with the libp2p stack through message passing.
In practice
You write an Actor that contains libp2p::Swarm and calls .next() on it, as well as a channel you poll concurrently (containing the commands you want to execute on the libp2p stack). This drives the event loop of libp2p, which is very critical. Disturbing this event loop, for instance by doing IO between polling the Swarm or even worse waiting for something to happen in the Swarm, results in strange behaviour, early closed connections or possibly even dead locks.
In the same actor and loop where you drive the Swarm you also want to receive "commands" from the rest of your application.
This is from my blog post about my application I built with libp2p:
pub async fn run(&mut self) {
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            event = self.swarm.next() => {
                self.handle_event(event.unwrap()).await
            },
            command = self.command_receiver.recv() => match command {
                Some(c) => self.handle_command(c).await,
                None => return,
            }
        }
    }
}

This design is also basically enforced by the Rust type system, since every operation on behaviours, like putting a message into gossipsub, requires mutable ownership of the Swarm. Here is the method to publish a message in gossipsub.
As a general rule do as little as possible in this libp2p actor. Only do the interaction with libp2p, like having a HashMap that contains the response channels (typically one shots), calling methods on the behaviour once you receive a command and matching the events you get out of the Swarm to those commands.
Why? (If you are interested)
libp2p is designed that way, because it makes it easier to reason about and it's more difficult to introduce errors. Every behaviour in libp2p is essentially a Finite State Machine that encapsulates all logic and is independent from the others.
Here is more about that in the rust-libp2p coding guidelines.
Complete example
The repository also contains a complete example on how to do what I just described (although with Kademlia but you'll figure it out).
I know this is all kind of unusual and strange, especially if you come from other libp2p implementations. But it's really great once you get used to it!
